# mysql - paginate groups of records not records it self

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pagination, doctrine

I have a problem that I don't know how to do pagination for this table where only information I got is how many results should be shown and what is the current page or what is the last record (or last group).

The thing is that I don't want for example to get the first 5 records but I want all records of the first 5 groups but records and groups can be removed, sorted in any order or filtered so I can't use ID or group ID columns to determine **from** which ID **to** which ID I want to paginate)

```
ID - Group (FK) - value
------------------------
1  - 1          - a 
2  - 1          - b
3  - 2          - c
4  - 2          - d
5  - 3          - e
6  - 2          - f
8  - 3          - g
9  - 2          - h
10 - 5          - i
11 - 5          - j
```

So when I want to get for example the second page and first 2 groups it should return:

```
ID - Group (FK) - value
------------------------
5  - 3          - e
8  - 3          - g
10 - 5          - i
11 - 5          - j
```

Or the first page of 3 groups

```
ID - Group (FK) - value
------------------------
1  - 1          - a 
2  - 1          - b
3  - 2          - c
4  - 2          - d
5  - 3          - e
6  - 2          - f
8  - 3          - g
9  - 2          - h
```

Or the second page of 3 groups

```
ID - Group (FK) - value
------------------------
10 - 5          - i
11 - 5          - j
```

But when the table is sorted for example:

```
ID - Group (FK) - value
------------------------
3  - 2          - c
4  - 2          - d
10 - 5          - i
11 - 5          - j
5  - 3          - e
1  - 1          - a 
2  - 1          - b
6  - 2          - f
8  - 3          - g
9  - 2          - h
```

Now I want the first 2 groups of page 1 it should return

```
ID - Group (FK) - value
------------------------
3  - 2          - c
4  - 2          - d
10 - 5          - i
11 - 5          - j
6  - 2          - f
9  - 2          - h
```